# Handling Headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin for Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine, fonts, font-face

I have been trying to get Firefox to load a custom font I have on a server that is not the one my Google App Engine project is in, I understand that this happens because my website and my font are not on the same server, and Firefox does not allow that.

I found on this question [Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555269/access-control-allow-origin-header-on-google-app-engine) how to allow different origins like you would on an htaccess file, but it seems to work only for files that you have on your server too.
I am trying this

```
- url: /wp-content(.*\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

, and I downloaded my files, to see if it would work locally, and it doesn't.
This is what I have, there is obviously something wrong with it, but I would really like to know how to add the handler here, so my font-face would still be loaded on another server and not with a remote link.

The font loads well on Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: I load a font from Google with no problems - never see this warning. How did you include this font in your page?

Comment: First I did it like this:  
    `@font-face {
      font-family: 'WebSymbolsLigaRegular';
      src: url("https://cic.mx/src/fonts/websymbolsligaregular.eot");
      src: url("https://cic.mx/src/fonts/webSymbolsLiga-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), ...`

Comment: @AndreiVolgin
Then I saved the font files on /wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts and the stylesheet is on wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css where I edited
    `font-family: 'WebSymbolsLigaRegular';
        src: url('fonts/websymbolsligaregular.eot');
        src: local('☺'), url('fonts/websymbolsligaregular.woff')...`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing a "/" in your url regex, i.e.

```
- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I load a font. In my HTML page:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then in my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial Unicode MS,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the font is not from Google, is a custom font I downloaded, but I am using Google App Engine for my hosting. I actually use the Open Sans font as well, and that one works fine, but I don't think or I don't know if there's a way I can load my font as a stylesheet.

Comment: Replace the URL with the link to your font. I am using it on App Engine too.

Comment: Still nothing on Firefox... :C