# How can I set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers for fontawesome's new CDN on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, font-awesome, cdn, app.yaml

Fontawesome just released [their own CDN](https://cdn.fontawesome.com/) and I am trying to use it on my Google Cloud's AppEngine like this:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/aa2b8cb467.js"></script>
```

But it gives the following error in Chrome's console:

> "Font from origin 'http://use.fontawesome.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

I read on [another Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555269/access-control-allow-origin-header-on-google-app-engine) that I can [configure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appref#handlers_element) my `app.yaml` to set these headers, but I don't know how to set these for external fonts.

```
handlers:
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
handlers:
- url: /use.fontawesome.com
  static_dir: ??
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.practia.org
```

And then I am thinking that it is not my application that needs to set these headers, but rather the CDN of fontawesome. If I understand, it is they who need to allow access from other origins to their CDN. Or am I missing something?

[image: The only options that can be set on cdn.fontawesome.com]

Answer (score 1):

You can not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on other sites, just on your own.

As you are requesting the file from `https://use.fontawesome.com/` it obviously is not your server.

It seems they are providing an unique file for each website `https://use.fontawesome.com/aa2b8cb467.js` - so I guess there should be a setting on their side that specifies allowed sites.

Probably you are suing it from the wrong host - check your setting on https://cdn.fontawesome.com/.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the only options that I could find on cdn.fontawesome.com. And there is nothing to set allowed sites.